# Cannot call `call` because: Either property `context` is missing in function flow error when using Redux-Saga?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, redux-saga, yield

I have a piece of code that is using the yield call api from redux saga which is calling a function and providing an input.

The function it is calling a simple POST function that returns a response when hitting an api.

The input for this function is a string called `code`, and that is set from a parameter in the url. We're using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to get a specific param from the URL based off a keyword.

The problem appears to be rooted in the fact that this URLSearchParams uses the window object to get the code. And that is causing an issue with yield call and giving me the following Flow error:

> Cannot call `call` because: Either property `context` is missing in
> function [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) but exists in  object type [2]. Or property `context` is
> missing in  function [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) but exists in  object type [3]. Or property
> `context` is missing in  function

Here is the code:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get('code');
const res = yield call(confirmCode, code); // This call is where the error is happening
```

And this is the confirmCode function it is calling:

```
export function confirmCode(code: string): Promise<TResp<void>> {
  return request(`/agent/v1/confirm-code/${code}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params.get('code');` returns `null | string` so in fact your issue is that `code` passed into `call` isn't compatible with `confirmCode`.

You can fix this in two ways either from the function definition which means you may want to add a default value to code

```
export function confirmCode(code: ?string): Promise<TResp<void>> {
  return request(`/agent/v1/confirm-code/${code}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
  });
}
```

Or check that `code` is valid before running `call`

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get('code');
if (code) {
  const res = yield call(confirmCode, code);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I chose the latter solution, I appreciate your explanation.